# How to capture JavaScript errors with Selenium4 and Junit5 using Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, junit5

How can I catch JS Eror messages using the automatic driver that comes with Selenium 4? And in order to use this in all my tests, should I define the test in @AfterEach? Or can everything be recorded automatically with a test class we wrote? What do I need to do in Junit5 to store incoming reports?I am sharing the driver class I use with you in case it may contribute to the solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4BkA.png) Thank you for all your help, good work

When I examined the previous answers to similar problems, I saw that these solutions were for before selenium4. For example, I know that there is no need to define drivers separately with Selenium4. I think that's why I failed when I tried to apply the previous methods.When I examined the previous answers to similar problems, I saw that these solutions were for before selenium4. For example, I know that there is no need to define drivers separately with Selenium4. I think that's why I failed when I tried to apply the previous methods.

Comment: how is JUnit related to JavaScript?

Comment: @Stultuske, Selenium tests, which include JavaScript execution, are often written as JUnit tests.

Comment: @Stultuske In the App I'm testing, I'm trying to catch JS errors in the browser console.